# Javascript if statement, adding string into guarantee number checker

Tags: javascript, php, if-statement

Currently I have this if statement which checks through numbers when registering a guarantee number in a gravity form, however I now need to check through the numbers with a mandatory string that a customer needs to enter immediately before the number as currently they're able to enter just the number and it will search though the guarantee registered numbers whether they have a string in front of them or not...

So for example = searching PO983278 or PT983279 instead of just checking 983278 or 983279.

**Below is a snippet of the current if statement which works great when just checking a number.
**

```
$productName     = $_POST['productName'];
$guaranteeNumber = preg_replace('/[^0-9 ]/','',$_POST['guaranteeNumber']);

if($productName === 'Product One') {
    if((300000 <= $guaranteeNumber) && ($guaranteeNumber <= 430000)) {
        $confirmation = guaranteeDbCheck($guaranteeNumber);
    } else {
        $confirmation = 'Invalid Number';
    }
} elseif($productName === 'Product TWO') {
    if((261000<= $guaranteeNumber) && ($guaranteeNumber <= 411000)) {
        $confirmation = guaranteeDbCheck($guaranteeNumber);
    } else {
        $confirmation = 'Invalid Number';
    }
}

echo $confirmation;
```

**So I'd like to be able to do something like...
**

```
if($productName === 'Product One') {
    if(('PO' + 300000 <= $guaranteeNumber) && ($guaranteeNumber <= 'PO' + 430000))
```

**But of course this doesn't work, any advice on if anyone has done something similar would be great!
**
Thanks!

Comment: Don't add "PO" to your numbers, strip "PO" from the input…

Comment: Thanks for the reply, currently the search isn't taking notice of any string in front so searches the numbers fine (the preg_replace at the start is stripping anything that's not numbers from the input), but because numbers in the database could potentially crossover e.g. PO20202 & PT20202, I need to search the string code in front as well as the number?

Comment: Separate the stripped variables from the original. Use the stripped on for your if statements and the original for searches.

Answer (score 0):

```
$productName = $_POST['productName'];
$guaranteeOriginal = $_POST['guaranteeNumber'];
$guaranteeNumber = preg_replace('/[^0-9 ]/','',$_POST['guaranteeNumber']);

if($productName === 'Product One') {
    if((300000 <= $guaranteeNumber) && ($guaranteeNumber <= 430000)) {
        $confirmation = guaranteeDbCheck($guaranteeOriginal);
    } else {
        $confirmation = 'Invalid Number';
    }
} elseif($productName === 'Product TWO') {
    if((261000<= $guaranteeNumber) && ($guaranteeNumber <= 411000)) {
        $confirmation = guaranteeDbCheck($guaranteeOriginal);
    } else {
        $confirmation = 'Invalid Number';
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah right, that's brilliant thanks for the help Daniel, worked a treat!